# Highmaps: How do you change the name of a state

Tags: highcharts

I need to change the name of a state in this map from the Highmaps map collection. Specifically, I need to change the name of the "Distrito Federal" to "CDMX". In the series data it is this point: ['mx-df', 10]. I've searched around for an answer, but am having trouble understanding how to do it. Anyone out there able to help?

Here's a link to a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sstoker/81w2revu/

Here's the HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/mx/mx-all.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
// Prepare demo data
// Data is joined to map using value of 'hc-key' property by default.
// See API docs for 'joinBy' for more info on linking data and map.
var data = [
    ['mx-3622', 0],
    ['mx-bc', 1],
    ['mx-bs', 2],
    ['mx-so', 3],
    ['mx-cl', 4],
    ['mx-na', 5],
    ['mx-cm', 6],
    ['mx-qr', 7],
    ['mx-mx', 8],
    ['mx-mo', 9],
    ['mx-df', 10],
    ['mx-qt', 11],
    ['mx-tb', 12],
    ['mx-cs', 13],
    ['mx-nl', 14],
    ['mx-si', 15],
    ['mx-ch', 16],
    ['mx-ve', 17],
    ['mx-za', 18],
    ['mx-ag', 19],
    ['mx-ja', 20],
    ['mx-mi', 21],
    ['mx-oa', 22],
    ['mx-pu', 23],
    ['mx-gr', 24],
    ['mx-tl', 25],
    ['mx-tm', 26],
    ['mx-co', 27],
    ['mx-yu', 28],
    ['mx-dg', 29],
    ['mx-gj', 30],
    ['mx-sl', 31],
    ['mx-hg', 32]
];

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: 'countries/mx/mx-all'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/mx/mx-all.js">Mexico</a>'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        name: 'Random data',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name + }'
        }
    }]
});
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 500px; 
    min-width: 310px; 
    max-width: 800px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.loading {
    margin-top: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the displayed information in tooltip and data label by using `formatter` function:

```
series: [{
    ...,
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
            if (this.point['hc-key'] === 'mx-df') {
                return 'CDMX';
            }

            return this.point.name;
        }
    }
}],

tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function() {
        if (this['hc-key'] === 'mx-df') {
            return 'CDMX: ' + this.value;
        }

        return this.name + ' ' + this.value;
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hry758v3/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.dataLabels.formatter

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/tooltip.pointFormatter